# Django website loads with empty root urls.py file

Tags: django, urlconf

I know it's feels like elementary, and yet I can't come up with a clean solution based on doc only. 
I have the following project structure (I omit files like models.py, forms.py for the purpose of keeping  the question concise)

- hello_world

  - hellow_world

    - urls.py
  - app_2

    - urls.py
  - app_3

    - urls.py
  - manage.py
  - urls.py
  - settings.py

As you see, my goal is to have a separate `urls.py` file for each app, and then assemble them into root `urls.py` (depicted at the same level as `settings.py` in the list above). The problem is that my root urls.py is EMPTY (!!!) now, and the site still loads the home page !!! What am I doing wrong ???
See the details below:

settings.py:

`ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'`

hellow_world urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home , name = 'home'),
]
```

root urls.py - empty !

manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) to include more urls:

```
# your main urls.py file
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapp1/', include('myapp1.urls')),
    url(r'^myapp2/', include('myapp2.urls')),
]
```

And:

```
# myapp1/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'myapp1'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    #...
]
```

Comment: but how can you explain the fact that the website loads correct url with EMPTY root urls.py ?

Comment: Does it mean that Django always looks into the module which has the same name as the project (in this example, hellow_world), and there is no need to include the urls.py for it ?

Comment: Your settings module is probably hellow_world.settings.py - it is hard coded in manage.py, check it out.  You should keep your main urls.py and settings.py there - this is the recommended setup.

Comment: I've added the manage.py file definition in the question. `You should keep your main urls.py and settings.py there - this is the recommended setup.` Could you please clarify what you mean by `there` ? It is really very important for me!

Comment: `settings.py` and `urls.py` should be in `mysite/mysite` while `mysite/myapp1` should contain `views.py`, `models.py` and `urls.py`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Now completely clear. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the quesiton.